# Apply css rule only to parent

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="sidebar" style="float:right;">
<li id="test" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">
<ul class="product-categories">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-45 current-cat cat-parent">
<ul class="children">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-76"></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-77"></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-78"></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-79"></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-80"></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-81"></li>
</ul>
</li>
</div>
```

**I would like to applay the css rule:**

```
background-color:red;
```

**only to the li with the .current-cat class**

So far i have managed to applay this rule to the all li whiche contain another ul inside so i get a big bulk of red instaed only the current li
iI used this rule:

```
ul > li.current-cat{background-color:#F98562;}
```

EDIT
with Vitorino Fernandes help i managed getting [TO THIS](http://www.davidsinay.com/product-category/clinical-labs/) as you can see the red line is still on the left side of the not choosen li.

Comment: Please explain what is the exact problem, and include your css also

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/5mff7Lj9/) the `.cat-item ` also takes the height of the `.current-cat` so set different background for sub-sub li like in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some unclosed tags

the `.cat-item` also takes the height of the `.current-cat` so the children will also take the background of parent

set different background for sub-sub li like in the example

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/5mff7Lj9/

**Edit**

added pseudo element `:before` for list styling as per your comment

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/5mff7Lj9/3/

```css
* {
  /* margin:0;
    padding:0;*/
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  /*list-style:none;*/
}
ul > li.current-cat {
  background-color: #F98562;
}
ul ul > li.current-cat li {
  background-color: white;
}
ul > li.current-cat ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li.current-cat ul li {
  padding-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
}
ul > li.current-cat ul li:before {
  content: '\25AA';
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li id="test" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">test1
      <ul class="product-categories">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-45 current-cat cat-parent">test2
          <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-76">test3</li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-77">test4</li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-78">test5</li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-79">test6</li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-80">test7</li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-81">test8</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: almost there, my code looks more like this now(after your seggestion)[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/5mff7Lj9/2/) take out the red color in the children bulletin and its perfect!

Comment: not working for me..please see this [link](http://www.davidsinay.com/product-category/clinical-labs/)

Comment: set `margin:0` for `.children` and add `background:white` for `ul > li.current-cat ul li` @Sinaydavid

Comment: hi thanks for your help... it made the nested li white but still you have red color on the side of the nested li's please see [HERE](http://www.davidsinay.com/product-category/clinical-labs/)

Comment: `#sidebar .sub-menu,#sidebar .children,.footer-area .sub-menu,.footer-area .children,#slidingbar-area .sub-menu,#slidingbar-area .children{margin-left:15px !important;}` this styles is overwriting remove `#sidebar .children` from there

Answer (score 1):

Try validating your HTML. You will find that it is not valid. The only valid child of `<ul>` is `<li>`, and you are not allowed to have a `<li>` inside a `<div>`.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context

Write like the following and your CSS should work:

```
<ul>
    <li class="current-cat"></li>
</ul>
```